# faulty component identification

Tags: components

The device in the picture, after a fall, no longer works, it doesn't detect the Open/Close status of the door. Structurally it hasn't been damaged.

I have reset and reconfigured it.

May be something has demagnetized after the fall ?

Can you recognize which element is it ?
[image]

Comment: Begin measuring resistors.  A broken (or not well soldered) but not visible ?

Comment: I suspect MK1 to be a reed switch (magnetically activated switch). It's a mechanical device and it might have been damaged by the fall.

Comment: Your post has no useful information.  What is this device?  What is it supposed to do?  What do you mean by "no longer works"?  What door?  What is the power source for the device?

Comment: MK1 also hasn't been properly soldered or the solder side via would have solder too. The board has been soldered by hand and there's numerous questionable joints. It is evidently a crap product or you would be getting a board made with pick & place reflow soldering.

Answer (score 2):

Repair guy here. The first thing to do is to check the power. Is the device powered at all? There could be no power due to short or something else. Check the voltage on the coil on any side(L1, gray square with 3R3) while it's supposed to be powered, then disconnect power and check resistance from the coil to the ground, should be high, kiloohms or mehaohms high.

If something is off there, it's either a shorted capacitor or a dead U2, which looks like a switching voltage regulator to me.

Another option is a dead chip that interfaces with the other devices, whatever it is. In this case I suspect it's a U1.

I don't think something got demagnetized or whatever.

That's the order you check stuff in. First check the power lines, if thing is unpowered, it won't work. If power is ok, you check the logic.